# Best approach Shortahand or Short-circuiting in Javascript

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

Which approach is most recommended. First or Second ?

```
function(x,y) {
  // 1
  var foo = x ? x.a : y;
  // 2
  var foo = x && x.a || y;
}
```

Comment: The best approach is to write good readable code.  Unless this function is being called hundreds or thousands of times, your best bet it to make it readable and maintainable (which x, y and x.a are not).

Comment: I would add, as a comment that your main objective should always be to be able to read it clearly in 6 months.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one

```
x ? x.a : y
```

returns with a truthy `x` a falsy value of `x.a`, where

```
x && x.a || y
```

returns `y` in this case.

To answer your question, it depends, if you have falsy values or not.

For a safe usage, depending only on `x`, you might use better the conditional operator.

Answer (score 1):

First one - ternary operations are mostly used in these cases and developers don't have to remember boolean operators precedence.

Answer (score -1):

In almost any other situation I prefer a ternary, but in the specific case of deep nesting I'd prefer short-circuiting. With deeper nesting it becomes:

```
var foo = (alpha && alpha.beta && alpha.beta.charely) ? alpha.beta.charley.delta : y
```

vs

```
var foo = (alpha && alpha.beta && alpha.beta.charely && alpha.beta.charley.delta) || y
```

It just feels like the former is already basically doing the latter, but then switching tactics on the last check. Just my opinion.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, neither.

I use a `get()` helper method that some other languages have build in, if all I'm trying to do in get some deep value (without throwing an error if I don't have the parent object). It also allows for specifying a fallback value if the value is *undefined*, rather than falsy. e.g.:

```
var foo = get(x, 'a', 'Not found') || 'Denied'
```

Here, if `x.a` doesn't exist, I get, 'Not found', and if it *does* exists, but is falsy, I get 'Denied'.

---

There's also an ["Optional Chaining" proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) for JavaScript (currently stage-1).

With it, the syntax would be:

```
var foo = x?.a || y;
```

or if you want to fallback to `y` only if it's specifically *undefined* (or null):

```
var foo = x?a ?? y;
```

using the ["Nullish Coalescing" proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-nullish-coalescing) (also stage-1).

Comment: Decided to write this as a separate answer since it's more a discussion of the (other)  options than choosing one.